# Power BI | Combine Measures into one VIsual

Tags: merge, measure

Alright - After completely checking google and all the forums I now really need help.

**The Situation:**

- There are two measures. One shows the "SUM" (222) and the other shows the "SUM%" in % (2,81%)
- If I show the each measures in an separate card visual, everything is fine

**The Need:**

- Combine these two measures into one card visual

**The Problem:**

- When I combine these two measures with "&" or "COMBINEVALUES", the % value completely freaks out and shows "2,80550992038418e-02". Yes, the Measure is formatted as percentage and limited to two decimal value places

Sounds easy - But seems impossible. Any Ideas? For now I need to combine only two measures - but maybe there is an solution to combine even more than only two measures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goddamnit! Sometimes the solution is so simple...

COMBINEDMEASURENAME = CONCATENATE([MEASURE 1], CONCATENATE(" (", FORMAT([Measure2WITH%], "0.00%)")))

With the [FORMAT-Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax) you can override the format of the measure and define it to fit your needs